# How to access delegate access's domain through godaddy api?

Tags: godaddy-api

I have a godaddy account and other account gives delegate access to my account. I want to operate on the domains of other account through api. Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: you can check this https://domainnamewire.com/2019/09/24/how-to-give-your-developer-access-to-just-one-domain-at-godaddy/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. See the GoDaddy [Statement of Support](https://www.godaddy.com/help/statement-of-support-api-platform-41068) (currently the last line of the last section).